# Run program on startup of every Windows computer in network

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

I have a computer network with about 50 computers running mostly Windows 7 and some of them running Windows 10.
How can I run a program on every computer:
 (1) after logon
 (2) on startup before logon

Comment: Are they part of a AD domain?  If so you can look into both login scripts and startup scripts I would think.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a domain, then you can do it using Group Policy.

If you are not on a domain, the only option I know of is to use Scheduled tasks.  This will work by default for computer start up (it is an option).  For user login, you'll have to use the Event Viewer event IDs as the only option in Task Scheduler is for when you log in (not all users).